# (zsh: command not found: python) MacOS VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-monterey

When I try to run the Python code on Visual Studio Code it says zsh: command not found: python. I'm sure the Python extension is installed on VS Code and I have Python 3.10.6 and I'm using macOS Monterey 12.5.1

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, the right command to run Python is `python3` instead of `python`. Make sure your scripts use `python3` for better compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the Python extension correctly, you should be able to run the Python code by clicking on the drop-down menu in the top left corner of VsCode's screen and clicking on "Run Python File"

Here is the Python extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python